# Boolean recursive function returning the wrong value

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a recursive function I did to find out if the given digits in a number are in a decreasing order, I'm sure my base is correct as I see the function does return false for the first few digits, but because the last two are in a decreasing order the function returns true in the end.

I can't figure out how to keep that false value and return it back to the original call for the function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool dec(int n);

void main()
{
    cout << dec(1231);
}

bool dec(int n)
{
    bool res;

    if (n < 10)
        return true;
    else
    {
        res = dec(n / 10);
        if ((n / 10) % 10 > n % 10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't using `res` at all. You're just assigning to it.

Comment: `if (x) { return true; } else { return false; }` is kind of an anti-pattern. Why not just `return x;`?

Comment: @cdhowie it doesn't work when I change it to `return res`.

Comment: @kuhaku Not `return res`, but the whole expression. For example, as per @b4hand's answer: `return res && (n / 10) % 10 > n % 10;`

Comment: @cdhowie I didn't know it could be done without the `if` `else`.

Comment: @kuhaku Yep. In `if (x)` the `x` is evaluated in bool context. In `return x` the `x` is evaluated in the context of whatever type the function returns, which is bool in this case -- so it's the same behavior. You can just return the bool result directly out of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only `return true` if `res` is also true. Try

```
return (res && (n / 10) % 10 > n % 10);
```

Comment: I thought about that but didn't believe it would work because of the recursion, but it does. Thanks.